# if statement display none javascript correspond to library tags {{IMAGE}}

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, getelementbyid

```
<div id="title1"><img src="a.jpg"></div>
<div id="title2"><img src="b.jpg"></div>
<div id="title3"><img src="c.jpg"></div>



<script type="text/javasctipt">
if ("{{IMAGE(z1)}}" = "") { document.getElementById('title1').style.display = "none"; }
if ("{{IMAGE(z2)}}" = "") { document.getElementById('title2').style.display = "none"; }
if ("{{IMAGE(z3)}}" = "") { document.getElementById('title3').style.display = "none"; }  
</script>
```

I like to have these div tags `title1, title2, title3` disappear when {{IMAGE(z1}}, {{IMAGE(z2}} and {{IMAGE(z3}} are not exist. These tags are the library tags for image uploads. In other words, When the image is not uploaded, these div tags will be `display: none`

But my javascript is not working, any idea why? Thanks in advance. Oh and Please I need this to be done in only Javascript, nojQuery please.

Source code example:

{{IMAGE(z1)}} is not uploaded,

```
<script>


if ("" = "") { document.getElementById('title1').style.display = "none"; }
                if ("http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/thumbnail2.jpg" = "") { document.getElementById('title2').style.display = "none"; }
                if ("http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/thumbnail3.jpg" = "") { document.getElementById('title3').style.display = "none"; } 
                if ("http://d3d71ba2asa5oz.cloudfront.net/40000483/images/thumbnail4.jpg" = "") { document.getElementById('title4').style.display = "none"; } 
                </script>
```

Comment: Your `if` assessments are flawed; the strings are not equal, and, for some reason, you're assigning the right-hand side string to the left-hand side. Which can't work, because a string isn't a variable, so you can't assign to it. What...are you *trying* to do?

Comment: the goal is to get rid of the div tags accordingly when the image is not uploaded, please refer to the source code example.